# Query optimization and database indexes

Tags: database, query, optimization

I noticed that there a handful of queries that ExpressionEngine runs that don't use any database indexes. An example is the query `SELECT DISTINCT ee.* FROM exp_extensions ee WHERE enabled = 'y' ORDER BY hook, priority ASC, class` which gets run on every page. Doing a MySQL `EXPLAIN` on this shows that it could benefit from a database index. However, since the number of extensions installed is usually fairly small, adding an index for this query might not be a huge win.

I realize that the official stance is to not add indexes because it could conflict with future updates. On the other hand, from a practical standpoint, I have to balance resource usage and page rendering speed against the official stance; also, I'm willing and able to removing indexes before upgrading to a newer version of ExpressionEngine.

Is there a set of queries that are prime candidates for database indexes that would reduce load on the MySQL server? Is there any best practice on this?

Comment: This is a really complicated question. I've got a "database best practices for EE" article in progress right now, but I don't know if it'll be finished by the end of 7 days. :)

Comment: @adrienne Looking through your comments, you have the makings of the best answer so far, so I look forward to your article. Unfortunately, I can't control the rules of bounty, if that's the 7-day issue.

Comment: Bryan, That's fine. :) I don't really care about the bounty; it'd be nice but it's not actually a big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any established best practices for adding indexes to DB tables. I'd say the official EllisLab stance is you shouldn't have to add any because they've done this work for you where needed.

But every project has different needs and developers have to evaluate this on a case by case basis depending on the project. In my years with EE, I've only needed to add one index to a large database that was struggling with a specific query. I'm not well versed in this area so perhaps I've needed it more and just didn't know. If you're going to add indexes to any table it will probably be the exp_channel_data table.

My advice is unless you are having specific resource issues with your DB server or can identify a specific query that is struggling, there shouldn't be reason to add an index. EE runs fine with its default DB settings for more projects.

A quick solution if you are having specific issues is to implement the [**CE Cache addon**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-cache). The speed increase when using the Static Driver is incredible... night and day difference in page load times... and it will immediately reduce any resource strain on the DB.

Comment: Disagree! Indices are *really important* for database performance, and EllisLab didn't add any to the default EE install. However, they're the sort of thing that is by and large best to tune to your particular situation.

I really do have an article in progress about this very issue, among others. I'll see if i can knock it out in the next couple days.

Comment: What do you disagree with? Sounds like we're saying the same thing. They are important but most sites won't need this kind of attention. It's something that is absolutely determined on a case by case basis. I look forward to reading this article. I can absolutely use some education in this area.

Comment: What i'm saying is that *most* sites can benefit from indices, not just a few big ones. It's just that people need to be aware of how to tune them because if you add too many they can *cause* performance problems rather than alleviate them.

Comment: It's not true that EE's default install is w/o indicies. It uses PRIMARY KEY, KEY or INDEX, two of the four available indices in MySQL. `exp_channel_titles` has the most KEYs and depending on your need, `exp_channel_data` probably has the most need for additional indices. But as both I and @Anna_MediaGirl mentions, there's not much standard about it. Slow queries aside, most speed is gained by Steve Souders' 80/20 rule. Reduce queries, reduce requests, consolidate, minimize, cache. Optimizing queries is just one part and works best when you identify frequently requested inefficient queries.

Comment: @nonprofit_tech Agree. However, we already do lots of the EE speed best practices. Optimizing queries is specifically what I'm asking about.

Comment: @Bryan I understand, I was just saying that I think its VERY dependent on what queries your doing. For example, if you had a lot of sorts based on a custom field (index it), if you needed to do a fulltext search or group two fields together like 'event name and presenter', then an index may help. But best practices would probably more about ideas of when, rather than specifics to what indices to add. I have an extra index on the members table for one client, but not for any other client. Most of our clients have under 5,000 members, one has 75,000. They need the extra index.

Comment: @Bryan Are you having specific issues? Is that why you're optimizing?

Comment: @nonprofit_tech is correct, sorry, I was unclear. EE does have some KEYs, and most of the tables also have PRIMARY KEYs. But in some cases (especially involving complicated channel:entries queries) it can be helpful to add additional indices of non-key types. The article I've got outlined is about best practices for how to think about data in EE; it's not going to be prescriptive about what columns to add indices to!

Comment: In MySQL, KEY and INDEX are the same thing, are they not? I don't mean PRIMARY KEY obviously. Either way, I don't expect blindly adding indexes to EE would help you much unless you have been watching New Relic or something for a while and know specifically which queries are wasting the most time on your site.

Comment: I think my answer should win because it's generated the most comments! :)

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl Good response times are a website feature. We've had some minor issues here and there, but nothing pressing. I'm just trying to build up knowledge on the issue. It's a question for which the community should have a realistic answer.

Comment: Bryan, for amazing response times I suggest installing CE Cache using their static driver. It will fix any issues you might be seeing and will load all pages flat file like speed.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl We have CE Cache installed. Helps immensely. But even it is not a silver bullet.

Comment: It's power is amazing. You might want to also hit StackOverflow to ask a more general non-EE question about rules of thumb for adding indexes. It's probably more appropriately asked there actually... though there are some good answers posted here too.

Answer (score 8):

I haven't heard of any best practices around this. I think it depends on the user, you. If you're looking for some best practices to improve speed, you may want to start with:

- Ellis Lab's [Handling Extreme Traffic](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/optimization/handling_extreme_traffic.html)
- Solspace's [Website Performance Guidelines](http://www.solspace.com/downloads/PerformanceGuidelines.pdf) (PDF)
- Matt Perry's [How to Make EE Faster](http://mattoperry.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/ee-scaling.pdf)
- .Net's [Optimise your ExpressionEngine site](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/optimise-your-expressionengine-site)

Generally speaking, I've heard of developers adding indexing for queries that are frequently used, that can benefit from them. I'm not certain if they drop the indexing before upgrades.

Answer (score 5):

Most of required indexes are already there.

What I usually do, is if I use custom sorting order with `exp:channel:entries` I add key on field that I sort by.

I.e. if I have `{exp:channel:entries orderby="title"}` I add index on `title` in `exp_channel_titles` table.

If I have `{exp:channel:entries orderby="my_custom_field"}` and `my_custom_field` is a custom field with ID `7` I add index on `field_id_7` in `exp_channel_data` table.

Answer (score 3):

For custom field columns that will be used in join statements I find its best to set the column type to an `int` or a `varchar(#)` and then index it as suggested.

You can also optimise the way EE gets its data from the database.

When EE queries the database for a set of channel entries it brings back a lot of data that is often not needed.

This includes joining all columns from `exp_channel_data`, `exp_members`, `exp_member_data` and `exp_channels` for the related data.

Changing the way that EE generates its queries for the Channels module will yield some impressive results.

I had fun changing the channel entries query by adding a new extension hook to the `build_sql_query` method and adjusting the returned columns and table joins using tag parameters.

While working on a big site pulling lots of database content in from many `{exp:channel:entries}` tags I found it necessary to create an add-on to better manage the size of returned database results and keep the memory footprint smaller. Adding SQL comments via a tag parameter is a small bonus to make SQL debugging much easier when searching the MySQL logs.

If you're interested feel free to take a look: http://ee-garage.com/nsm-turbo-channels.

Please note that this version is rather experimental, hasn't been updated in a while and was never officially released.

Hopefully it will give you some ideas on how you can make EE's database functions run faster for you.

Answer (score 0):

EE has a lot of indexes already, so it's fairly rare to run into a situation where you'd need another. However, I see no reason to avoid doing it if you see measurable performance gains in a custom query or something. You can always drop it later if something changes.

I got a very modest performance boost on my site by adding an index to the `file_name` column of `exp_files`. The file field tag pair can get a bit slow without that index if you have a huge number of files.

As far as your `exp_extensions` example goes, it's probably a bad candidate because there are only two options for `enabled` (y/n). It *might* be beneficial if you had thousands of rows and only a few were marked 'y', but as a general rule of thumb it's best to use indexes on columns with lots of unique values.